# htaccess is creating the virtual link, but the url is not changing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create SEO friendly URL's for only a couple of specific links using htaccess.

This is what I have so far that's half working:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiviewsRewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^link-i-want/?$ file.php?notextensioniwant=1$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now this is working to an extent, It's creating the viewable http://mydomain.com/link-i-want but it's not redirecting http://mydomain.com/file.php?notextensioniwant=1 to http://mydomain.com/link-i-want

I've seen a LOT of relatively similar threads on here, but none have worked or helped me out.

I think I've about viewed every question similar to this, but haven't got an answer, so apologize in advance if it's a repost.

Answer (score 0):

With current code `http://mydomain.com/file.php?notextensioniwant=1` this won't redirect to `http://mydomain.com/link-i-want`.

Only `http://mydomain.com/link-i-want` will rewrite to `http://mydomain.com/file.php?notextensioniwant=1` by default.

You will have to write extra rules for it.
But this may cause redirection loop to each other. You may try to manage it with PHP end.

Comment: Any chance you could share the extra rules I need to add? Thanks.

Comment: These rules
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^notextensioniwant=1$
RewriteRule ^.* http://localhost/albabar/link-i-want/ [R=301,L]`
will redirect `http://mydomain.com/file.php?notextensioniwant=1` to `http://mydomain.com/link-i-want`.
But as I said, it will create a redirect loop to each other as well.